# Anymore in Affirmative Sentences

Tags: adverbs, polarity-items

Do you use *anymore* in the meaning of "no longer" only in negative or interrogative sentences? Will it be grammatical, if I use that adverb in the affirmative sentence?

> I see no possibility of managing this problem of climate change **anymore**.

Comment: No.  *anymore* cannot be used like that. "I no longer see any possibility..." or "I do not see the possibility of managing...any longer".  The problem with this particular sentence is the combination of "possibility" and "anymore".

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_anymore

Comment: @TRomano OP's example *I see no possibility any more* is fine: what it "affirms" is a negative, which licenses *any more*.

Comment: @StoneyB: if we relocate *anymore* so that it comes after "possibility", then it  works; but if we leave it where it is, it doesn't.  In sentence-final position, "any longer" still works.

Comment: @TRomano I agree that it's *clearer* if you move it closer to the verb it is presumably intended to modify, *see*, but it's not wrong where it sits. I don't think any reader would take it to modify *managing*, precisely because that's *not* negated.

Comment: @TRomano, Stoney, Stoney's 100% right on this (I think he's trying to bend over backwards to be accommodating, in fact!). The OP's first sentence is fine :)

Comment: @Araucaria: Maybe you and StoneyB can help me understand why OP's sentence struck my ear as "off". In addition to the effect of *anymore* being placed so far from the verb it negates,  my ear may be hearing "deixis-discord" from common patterns whose *anymore* points in opposite directions, so to speak:  "I *see no* reason anymore {to do something}" and "It's *impossible* anymore {to do something}". In the first formulation, the speaker would abandon a practice; in the second, the speaker would continue if it were possible.  In OP's sentence, am I hearing both?  "I see no possibility of...".

Comment: @TRomano Erm, I've had a cogitate for several days, and my honest answer is I don't really know ... !

Comment: @Araucaria: I will have to blame the tree pollen (and too much Benedryl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Standard use (whatever that is), *any* is a [Negative Polarity Item](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item)—it is used only in negative contexts.

Note, however, that your example *I see no possibility of managing this problem of climate change anymore* provides that negative context: you speak of ***no*** possibility, and that licenses *any more* (or *anymore*).

In dialect use, however, the temporal expression *any more* is occasionally used in positive contexts, with the sense of being the antonym of the temporal expression *not any more*, meaning "no longer". It has thus two possible senses. If the ordinary negative

> He doesn't go there any more.

means *He used to go there but now he does not*, the positive version

> He's going there any more<sup>†</sup>

may mean either

> 1. He used to go there and he still does. *(This was the sense when I heard the expression, and I think the sense in Yohann V.'s Lawrence quotation.)*

or

> 2. He didn't go there in the past, but now he does.  *(This is the sense in Yohann V.'s Pynchon quotation.)*

Only the context can inform you which is meant.

But both are non-Standard uses; avoid them.

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>This is in fact an actual utterance which I heard in the Missouri Ozarks in 1982 and remembered because it was the first time I had ever encountered positive *any more*.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

While you are using a negative (*"**no** possibility"*) and talking about a negative sentence, it is possible to use it in both forms under conditions. [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/any_more#English) gives three possible usages :

> **any more** (not comparable)
>
> - (in **negative** or **interrogative** constructions) From a given time onwards; longer, again.
>
> *They don't make repairable radios any more.*
>
> - (colloquial, chiefly Northern Ireland, US, in **positive** constructions) Now, from now on.
>
> 1920, DH Lawrence, Women in Love:
>
> > *‘Quite absurd,’ he said. ‘Suffering bores me, any more.’*
>
> 2009, Thomas Pynchon, Inherent Vice, Vintage 2010, page 268:
>
> > *He's no longer the wholesome Chamber of Commerce bigshot we used to know in the olden days, Doc, he's bad shit anymore.*
>
> - To a greater extent (than).
>
> *I don't like Braques any more than I like Picasso.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use it exactly like your example. See http://www.thefreedictionary.com/anymore for an example very much like yours.

Comment: Where's the exact analogue?

Comment: Their example is, "We promised not to quarrel anymore." In general, you can say "Someone is not doing X anymore" or similar sentences.

Comment: I understand and accept that usage, but don't consider it by any means an exact analogue to the issues that arise in the OP's question.

Comment: Hmm, because of the presence of the word "possibility"? I just don't see how that changes the grammar. Would you dispute that, "We can't manage climate change anymore" is a valid sentence?

Comment: No dispute on the "We can't manage climate change anymore". But the OP's sentence becomes marginal for me with the combo of "see no *possibility of* managing" and a sentence-final "anymore".

Comment: I don't see how that matters. "There used to be a possibility, but there is no possibility anymore." That seems like a perfectly valid sentence to me.

Comment: I think TRomano objects to putting *any more* at the end, because it may lead a reader to understand that phrase to modify *managing* rather than *no possibility*. It is indeed an arguable position.